# How can I 301 redirect domain.com/tag/* to domain.com/blog/tag/*

Tags: wordpress, directory, http-status-code-301, blogs

I am trying to redirect links to domain.com/tag/* to domain.com/blog/tag/*
(where * is the actual tag name - eg music so domain.com/tag/music would redirect to domain.com/blog/tag/music)

I have been trying but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) /blog/tag/$1 [L,R=301]
```